# GridSplitter resize in WPF

Tags: wpf

I've a grid with 3 rows.When I drag down to grid splitter,the grid splitter disappeared.But I need to do  "auto" height of the first row.How can I fix this problem?

Here is code:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Border Background="BlueViolet" Height="20" Margin="3"/>
        <Border Background="BlueViolet" Height="20" Margin="3"/>
        <Border Background="BlueViolet" Height="20" Margin="3"/>
        <Border Background="BlueViolet" Height="20" Margin="3"/>
        <Border Background="BlueViolet" Height="20" Margin="3"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <GridSplitter Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Height="5"/>
    <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="GridSplitter here.." Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    <Border Background="CornflowerBlue" Grid.Row="2" Margin="3"/>        

</Grid>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it does not disappear. You set its Background to `White`. Just try using a different color, such as `Red`. You'll see it clearly.

Comment: Sorry,I can drag gridsplitter . My problem isn't color. If you can try this code. You can see the problem.Thanks.

Comment: actually I tried it, ss here http://i.imgur.com/xbAj61Q.png I changed the background to `Red`. As you can see, the red line is there. I can also drag it.

Comment: As you can see, here http://i.imgur.com/ZoOFict.png?1   gridsplitter is slipping down

Comment: Drag it to the bottom,it will be lost

Comment: That behavior seems to be caused by `Height="Auto"` (you set for the first row). You can try setting some `MaxHeight` for that row. However it should be ideal if we can bind that `MaxHeight` to the `ActualHeight` of the Grid.

Comment: In fact,I wrote minHeight for third row but still didn't work.I will try your suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not just use * for 0 and 2 and be done with it.

Comment: Because it remains gaps between the first and second rows.Here link   http://i.imgur.com/EBIkzu8.png?1  and that's my main project. Here link http://i.imgur.com/KMn0jjD.png?1.

Comment: But that is what a GridSplitter does. I get you want like a Default=Auto but it does not do that.  You might be able to measure in the Loaded Event.

Comment: I see.I will try do that from code behind.Thanks for your help.